# Refactoring method signature to take object instead of 1 or more of its properties

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have a method that takes multiple properties from an object and I want to safely refactor it to simply take the entire object.

I want to change:

```
var control = new Control
{
    Prop1 = 1,
    Prop2 = 2
};
TheMethod(control.Prop1, control.Prop2, "foo");
```

Into:

```
var control = new Control
{
    Prop1 = 1,
    Prop2 = 2
};
TheMethod(control, "foo");
```

I could not find a ReSharper refactoring that can help. Is there a series of steps I can perform that will safely do this refactoring?

Comment: That's known as "Introduce Parameter Object"
http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html

Comment: Not quite, as I don't want to create a new object, I want to use an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ReSharper's [Change Signature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html?search=change%20signature) refactoring to change the method's signature as you like. You can specify a default value for the newly introduced parameter (of type `Control`). If that doesn't handle all your cases, you can then use [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Navigation_and_Search__Structural_Search_and_Replace.html?search=replace) to replace the method's parameters as you see fit.

Comment: Using Change Signature has been the best option I've found so far. The method's caller already has an instance of the object, so that gets passed in, then I introduce temporary variables with the same name as the parameters I want to remove then manually delete the parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing the method's parameters of Prop1 and Prop2 to pass the type Control would look like this:

```
    TheMethod(Control control, string value)
    {
    }
```

Comment: His question is in terms of resharper refactoring it, he already posted he knows how to do the normal conversion.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it manually, I wanted to know if there was a built-in refactoring to handle it. I'm also thinking of a set of steps that can be repeated, such as this method for converting a static method into an instance method https://www.nickgoede.com/refactoring/resharper/2015/04/15/make-methods-non-static.html